# Easiest way to check if list element in other list element?

Tags: python, list

```
    a = ['ava','olivia','hannah','olivia']
    b = ['aa','ab','ac','av']

    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            if j in i:
                print (i)
    #output: ava


    for i in a:
        if any(j in i for j in b):
            print (i)
    #output: ava
```

There are 2 lists with some elements, I want to the if each list 2 elements in each list 1 elements.

There are any better way to get it?

Answer (score 5):

This is enough:

```
print [word for word in a if any(part in word for part in b)]
```

No need to use `filter`, `map` or `lambda`.

Comment: indeed, this looks better, +1

Comment: #output ['ava'],    

but really looks better

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily better, but they're oneliners:

```
a = ['ava','olivia','hannah','olivia']
b = ['aa','ab','ac','av']

result = filter(None, map(lambda x: x if any(map(lambda y: y in x, b)) else None, a))
print result
```

or:

```
result2 = filter(None, [x if y in x else None for x in a for y in b])
print result3
```

or:

```
result3 = filter(None, [x if any([y in x for y in b]) else None for x in a])
print result2
```